# if $a_1 \cdot b \equiv a_2 \cdot b (\text{mod }n)$ then $a_1 = a_2$

Tags: number-theory, modules

Assume $a_1 \cdot b \equiv a_2 \cdot b (\text{mod }n)$ and also $a_i^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ mod $n \in \{1, n-1\}$ and $b^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ mod $n \notin \{1, n-1\}$, I saw the following which proves $a_1 = a_2$. I would like to know is it right? if yes why?

#### Proof

Multiplying the congruence from right by $b^{-1}$, we obtain
$$
a_1 = a_1\cdot b \cdot b^{-1}  \text{ mod } n= a_2 \cdot b \cdot b^{-1} \text{ mod } n = a_2
$$

---

By multiplying $b^{-1}$ from right, we get $a_1 \text{ mod } n$ and $a_2 \text{ mod } n$ not $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then why is it true?

Comment: This is fine provided you know $b$ is a unit mod $n$ (which seems to be the case) and $a_1, a_2$ belong to the same interval of length $n$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein 
I added two more details, I would be appreciated if you take a look at it,

Comment: @Bernard 
I added two more details, I would be appreciated if you take a look at it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conclusion $\,a_1\equiv a_2,\,$ it is true iff $\,b\,$ is invertible mod $n\,$ (iff $\,\gcd(b,n)=1)$

Else $b,n$ share a divisor $c>1$ so $\,\color{#c00}{(n/c)}b = n(b/c)\equiv 0\equiv \color{#c00} 0\cdot b,\,$ but $\,\color{#c00}{n/c\not\equiv 0}\pmod n$

But your hypothesis does not imply that $b$ is invertible. Indeed it is true  for all noninvertible $b,\,$ i.e. they cannot have a power that is invertible since then they would be a factor of an invertible hence also invertible. Perhaps you meant instead that some power of $b$ is $\,\equiv \pm1$ (or invertible). Then it is true, since, as said, that implies that $b$ is invertible, hence cancellable mod $n$.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not true in general unless $\gcd(n, b) = 1$.

For instance $2 \cdot 3 = 4 \cdot 3 \pmod 6$ but $2 \not \equiv 4 \pmod 6$.

The problem is that here $3$ is not invertible since it is not relatively prime to $6$.

Comment: I added two more details, I would be appreciated if you take a look at it,

Comment: Those two details really change the nature of your question.  It is kind of bad form to ask a question, get an answer and then edit the question to be something different than what you asked originally.  But if $b^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv \pm 1$, then square both sides and you have $b\cdot b^{n-2} \equiv 1$ which shows $b$ has an inverse and you can proceed as you outlined.